# MSBuild Packge target and WebPublishTargetsVersion property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity

Hey there I could really use a guru on msbuild.

Ultimate goal: Build web deployment packages with TeamCity

I'm trying to call the Package target in TeamCity on my build server and it fails as path: Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.5 doesn't exist. 10.5 doesn't exist on my dev laptop either, I am using VS 2012, yet I can call MSbuild package target on the command line of my laptop with no problem.

I could make a copy of Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0 that does exist on the build server and rename it 10.5, but this just feels wrong.

Any pointers gratefully received.

**EDIIT**

For now I have just:

1. created the path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.5"
2. Copied contents of V10.0 into it.
3. Copied "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\web\Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets" into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of getting the VisualStudioVersion right, override it on the command line and all is good.

```
C:\>msbuild web_site.publishproj /T:Package /P:Configuration=Release;PackageLocation=C:\packages;VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```